# CSS Sticky Footer Menu - layout broken when Inspecting Element

Tags: html, css, layout, sticky-footer

i have made a css sticky footer menu which is working great apart from when you Inspect Element with FF, the footer menu jumps up about 100px. So when the Firebug window is visible the menu is floating halfway up the page!?

I have set body and the html to height 100% and also i have a container div which has height 100% aswell...Any ideas?

EDIT: I have just tried setting the container div to overflow: auto. The menu no longer float halfway up the page but i have vertical scrollbars??

Relevant CSS:

```
#menu {
width: 960px;
height: 100px;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
background-color: rgba(65, 64, 64, 0.75);
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you care if it *only* "breaks" when you're inspecting it with Firebug?

Comment: As a web dev, i'm constantly Inspecting Elements on other people's site...this would put me off a bit if it broke their layout...

Comment: Does it still break if you: open your site, open Firebug in its own window, then inspect the element?

Comment: Nope, it doesnt. It must be the fact that the Firebug window appears at the bottom of the site and pushes the menu up

Comment: I somehow thought it was that. In that case, the effect should be the same as not using Firebug in any way, and then reducing the height of your window by the same amount of height as the Firebug window is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross browser CSS sticky footers are impossible to do with a single rule. I would hazard a bet this will not work in IE. For a rock solid css sticky footer implement take a look [here](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html)

Comment: Yeah, that one's prooven, I use it always.

Answer (score 0):

You have to take into consideration, when firebug is loading it actually posts it's own styles in there to highlight element(s).  You can try inspecting the element in Chrome/Safari for a less invasive highlighting.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you should have your menu outside of your container directly below <body>